# Serializing dates without time component to JSON

Tags: json

Is there an informal standard for serializing dates that aren't meant to have a time component to JSON?
This date's time component is meaningless and the value should not be localized.

Comment: [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Dates) Dates

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov I wound up using ISO 8691. If you care to put it in an answer I'd go ahead and mark it resolved.

Comment: Nah, the link is not suitable for an answer, I believe. Write the answer yourself.